# jquery: toggle div with smooth effect

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    //$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $('#slidingDiv').fadeOut('500');
});
```

but it collapse div very fast

this is my script:

```
<div class="search-form" id="search-form">
    <div class="slidingDiv" id="slidingDiv">
        Content goes here
    </div>
    <a class="show_hide" id="show_hide" style="display: inline;">Search slider</a>
</div>
```

When I click on bottom grey bar I want to toggle **slidingDiv** div `Up/Down` with slow/smooth effects.
I tried all codes but it toggle very fast though I set time delay also.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer values instead a string to represent the milliseconds.

Try:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(){
    //$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    $('#slidingDiv').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

higher the number, slower the effect.